# c# - What does {string[0]} mean?

Tags: c#, arrays

### Setup:

Having a dumb day.

I have the following code:

```
UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username);
```

### Problem:

If username is an empty string ("", user not logged in), then when I check the value of `UserRoles` in the immediate window it shows:

```
{string[0]}
```

### Question:

What is `{string[0]}`?

How can I replicate this value to test my code for the case of an unlogged in user (username == "")?

NOTE: I have googled for this but to no avail.

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered this.  It was impossible to choose who to give the biscuit to, so went with the popular vote...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GetRolesForUser returns an array of roles, so the "String[0]" in the immediate window just means that it knows the return type is an array (in this case strings), but there are zero entries (since no roles are returned for a blank user.

Comment: @awrigley What do you want to replicate?

Comment: See my answer on how to create an empty string array.

Comment: Just to clarify - so I can get you the right answer - you want to replicate the {String[0]} in testing?

Comment: Thorsten's example will replicate an empty string object.  If your trying to get it in the UserRoles object, I'm guessing you can either pass in an empty string on you GetRolesForUsers call, or use Thorsten's "= new string[0];"

Comment: I just want to test the case when the user is not logged into the system.  So I need to be able to create an array with zero entries.  I suppose new string[]() would do?  Will try that.

Comment: @awrigley - that should work - or you can hard code a username that you know is not logged in.

Comment: Ray K:  I don't want to involve asp.net membership in my test.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the documentation of [Roles.GetRolesForUser(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx) you will see that it returns an array of strings: `string[]`

`{string[0]}` means that you have an array with zero elements.

Answer (score 3):

It's an empty array of strings. You can create an empty string array like

```
string[] emptyArray = new string[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is how the immediate window shows an empty array of strings:

```
[Test]
public void StringsTest()
{
    var strings = new string[] {};
}
```

In your test code you could [Mock](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Matching_Arguments) IRoles and have GetRolesForUser(username) return new string[] {}

Answer (score 1):

It means the value is an array of strings with 0 elements in it